# Getting a value from ArrayList c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

Hi I'm not to sure how to do this but here's the code that I've got

```
// splits 1 to 3
int check;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    check = alM1((rand.next(20))+1);//error
    if (!(alM3.Contains(check)))
        alM3.Add(check);
    if (alM3.Length == 10)
        break;
}
// removes 3 from 1
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (alM1.Contains(alM3(i)))  //error
        alM1.Remove(alM3(i));    //error
}
```

The error message says ArrayList is a variable but it is used like a method. 
How can I write it so it produces what I want. 
Thank in advance T

Comment: to access array list entries you have to use `al[i]`, not `al(i)`

Comment: check = alM1((rand.next(20))+1);//error - There are too more closing brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access entries of the list you need to use square bracket notation.
For example:

```
check = alM1[(rand.next(20))+1];
```

and:

```
if (alM1.Contains(alM3[i]))
```

Comment: Hi I've got the second one working thanks. But the top one no thanks for help

Comment: Veritable being used like a method

Comment: Got it. Check = (int)alM1[(rand.next(20) + 1)];  had to cast object to int. thanks for help have a nice day